# Passport.js OAuth2 TokenError -> OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Hello to whoever is willing to read this. After having browsed through every somewhat related question on StackOverflow (and other sites) to try and get a grasp of the cause of my problem, I have decided to ask a question here myself.

First of all, I was trying to follow along a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBvmnHTQIPY) (came up to around the 1h mark, YouTube timestamp/chapter details provide a good overview on what that covers, but I can summarize if needed) on how to implement an OAuth2 login/workflow in a Node.js Express app. The main difference here is that I wanted to use a different Passport / OAuth2 strategy, for which [passport-oauth2](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-oauth2/) seemed to be a good solution.

Anyway, the App works fine until it comes to the `/callback` part, where I get this error (in the console and as the page content):

```
TokenError
  at OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (D:\User\Documents\OAuth-App\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:373:12)
  at OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (D:\User\Documents\OAuth-App\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:420:16)
  at D:\User\Documents\OAuth-App\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:177:45
  at D:\User\Documents\OAuth-App\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:191:18
  at passBackControl (D:\User\Documents\OAuth-App\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\User\Documents\OAuth-App\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
  atIncomingMessage.emit (node:events:377:35)
  at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1312:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

The authorization server actually does return an auth code and the state, so it seems to me like it *should* work, but as I haven't programmed something like this before (using passport), maybe I just handled something wrong...? I also should have entered the correct redirect url on the API's config page (`http://localhost:3000/auth/api/callback`).

Morgan also logs this (edited code and state to reduce length):

```
GET /auth/api/callback?code=<around-900-chars>&state=<around-20-chars> 500 799.673 ms - 1103
```

I have defined the strategy in a js file, that gets required (`require("./config/passport")(passport);`) in the main app.js, like this:

```
const OAuth2Strategy = require("passport-oauth2").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/User");

module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(
        new OAuth2Strategy(
            {
                authorizationURL: process.env.API_URL + "/v1/oauth2/authorize",
                tokenURL: process.env.API_URL + "/v1/oauth2/token",
                clientID: process.env.API_CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.API_CLIENT_SECRET,
                state: true,
                pkce: true,
                callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/api/callback",
            },
            async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
                // ... code doesn't reach here
                console.log(profile);
            }
        )
    );

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, user) => done(err, user));
    });
};
```

My auth routes look like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const router = express.Router();

// @desc    Auth with API
// @route   GET /auth/api
router.get("/api", passport.authenticate("oauth2"));

// @desc    API auth callback
// @route   GET /auth/api/callback
router.get(
    "/api/callback",
    passport.authenticate("oauth2", {
        failureRedirect: "/",
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.redirect("/dashboard");
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

and are defined in the main app.js like this:

```
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
```

If there is any other info I can/should supply, please let me know. Otherwise... I really don't know what I should/could do to fix this.

Some of the sources/info pages I checked before:

- [Passport-OAuth2 Github PKCE tests](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/blob/master/test/oauth2.pkce.test.js)
- [The analogous Github Repo from the Tutorial](https://github.com/bradtraversy/storybooks) (to get an overview, compare it with my implementation)
- [PKCE with OAuth2 Passport](https://medium.com/passportjs/pkce-support-for-oauth-2-0-e3a77013b278)